# CAR represent *right* subtree of a cons?

Tags: list, tree, lisp, common-lisp

I am reading "ANSI Common Lisp" by Paul Graham, in $3.8 (page 40) it goes:

"Conses can also be considered as binary trees, with the car representing the right subtree and the cdr representing the left."

To me it sounds like the "right" and "left" were used wrongly at opposite positions....then I took a look of the online errata but it's not one of the items listed there...

http://www.paulgraham.com/ancomliser.html

Can anyone help to clarify this?

Btw, on the next page (p41), Paul said that "Binary trees without interior nodes are not useful for much." I don't fully understand it either. what does it mean by "without interior nodes"? A deeply nested list can have as many internal/interior nodes (i.e., conses) as you want, why he said "without"? or probably he just meant that these interior nodes, if present, does not contain atom values?

Thanks,
/bruin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, it would have been better if the text had said simply:

*Conses can also be considered as binary trees, with the car representing **one** subtree and the cdr representing the **other** subtree.*

Which is chosen for left and which for right is arbitrary. (Of course, consistency etc.) Perhaps the text had already introduced a concrete representation? Or perhaps it did so later, and needed to refer to which was which? If not -- if that statement was all there was, then I think there is no reason to choose sides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I am more confortable now...I was questioning myself that there must be something very basic I don't know if there is a solid reason behind the choice of left/right as in the text :) Btw, the text is followed by an example in boxed diagram showing the conventional left/right choice (i.e., car for left, cdr for right), which is contradictary to the previous text...

Answer (score 3):

In Lisp syntax, `car` is indeed the left half of a pair `cdr` the right half.

As for interior nodes, I suppose Graham means *unlabeled* interior nodes. E.g. you will much more often encounter trees like

```
(+ (* x y) z)
```

which should be thought of as trees built out of triples, even though implemented in terms of pairs, than trees of the form

```
((a . b) . (c . d))
```

Answer (score 3):

> Conses can also be considered as binary trees, with the car
>   representing the right subtree and the cdr representing the left.

You're right to pick up that this seems unconventional.  It should probably say that the `car` would represent the *left* subtree and that the `cdr` would represent the *right* subtree.  That said, trees (as well as lists) built from cons cells are *intensional* data structures.  We make a decision about how to to represent structures using cons cells, and then think in terms of that representation, not in terms of the cons cells. So, when we're writing list processing code, we'd prefer

```
(defun mapcar1 (fn list)
  (cons (funcall fn (first list))
        (mapcar fn (rest list))))
```

to

```
(defun mapcar1 (fn list)
  (cons (funcall fn (car list))
        (mapcar fn (cdr list))))
```

because we think of a list as having a first element, and there being a *rest* of the list., even though both would work.  It's just a coincidence that because of implementation, `car` and `cdr` would work too.  (Of course, this is a leaky abstraction when we notice that we have functions named, e.g., `mapcar` and `nthcdr` instead of `map` (well, there *is* a `map` function, but it's a little different) and `nthrest` or `nthtail`.

Similarly, we'd have to make a choice about representing binary trees with cons cells.  It doesn't *really* make a difference whether you do:

```
(defun make-tree (left right)
  (cons left right))

(defun left (tree)
  (car tree))

(defun right (tree)
  (cdr tree))
```

or

```
(defun make-tree (left right)
  (cons right left))

(defun left (tree)
  (cdr tree))

(defun right (tree)
  (car tree))
```

because you *ought* to be using `make-tree`, `left`, and `right` rather than `cons`, `car`, and `cdr` when you're working with trees.

> Binary trees without interior nodes are not useful for much.

He's referring to binary trees whose internal nodes don't have values of their own.  For instance, in a binary search tree, a node doesn't only have a left and right subtree, it has an associated value (or element). A binary search tree node is really a *triple* (element, left, right), not a pair (left, right).  Some problems can be solved with binary trees whose nodes don't have an associated value, but for many problems, you'll want nodes that hold two pointers (to left and right subtrees) in addition to a value.

Comment: Thanks for your answers to both questions. The term "intensional" data structure is new to me, but I think I got a bit sense out of it by reading the following text, also reading "Chapter 13" of Peter Seibel's book "Practical Common Lisp": data structure made from cons can be viewed through different lens according to your intension (on how to interpret it), pretty much like how a database schema can have multiple views...

Comment: The second question is due to my unfamiliarity with trees made up from nodes of pairs instead of triples. I was reading some introductary material saying that list data structure

Comment: ...can be nested thus it's essentially a tree, which is versatile enough to do many things...then I was a bit stuck on figuring out how pair-noded trees can be recognized as conventional triple-noded trees...Now, in the abstract sense (i.e., w/o considering the cons impelementation), how a lisp list can be interpreted as trees? I guess the answer is also depends on intensions...one possible way, i think, is to treat car as the parent of cdr, thus a list can be viewed as a conventional triple-noded tree. e.g. (+ 1 2) is a tree with root being + which has two kids 1 and 2 as leaves...

Comment: @bruin Lisp lists are already implemented as trees (and as cons cells).  A list is either the symbol `nil` (i.e., the empty list) or a cons where the `car` is the _first_ element of the list and the `cdr` is the _rest_ of the list (i.e., is another list).

Comment: @bruin E.g., see [this image](http://scientopia.org/img-archive/goodmath/img_119.jpg).  The second, "poorly balanced tree" (aside from the `5` node) is a binary tree, but has the same structure as a list.   You can view Lisp lists as the ultimate poorly balanced tree.

Comment: @bruin [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BinarySearchTree/treeStructure3.gif) and [this](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp212/07-spring/lectures/34/unbalancedtree.png) are even better examples.  Lists and binary trees (without interior nodes) are two things that you can implement when you have a "pair" data structure available.

Comment: then what about ((1 2 3) 4 5) under this view? which one of 1, 2, and 3 should be the parent of 4/5? this seem leading to some ambiguity...or, probably the parent for 4 and 5 is not 1 or 2 or 3, but the tree (1 2 3)...

Comment: @bruin Do you mean to treat that as a list?  If so, then it's a cons whose first element (`car`) is the list `(1 2 3)` and the rest of which (`cdr`) is the list `(4 5)`.  If you mean to treat it as a tree, then it's a tree whose left subtree (`car`) is the tree `(1 2 3)` and whose right subtree (`cdr`) is the tree `(4 5)`.

Comment: thanks. yes, I meant to treat ((1 2 3) 4 5) as a tree, but not as a tree without interior nodes...it's a kind of exploring the idea of "intensional"... as I still see trees without interior nodes a bit strange, so I want to see if there is a way to interprete a list as a tree *with* interior nodes :)

Comment: @bruin Sure, then.  You just need to define what the representation is.  You might, for instance, define a tree node as either either: an element (an atom, perhaps); or a list of the form `(left element right)`.  In that case, then `((1 2 3) 4 5)` is a binary tree with `4` at the root, a left subtree of `(1 2 3)` (which is a tree with `2` at its root and left and right subtrees of `1` and `3`), and a right subtree of `5`.

Comment: that's neat! and for lists with more than 3 elements, just take the cddr of the list as `right`, then this intepretation seems still working w/o ambiguity.

Comment: A tree is a kind of graph. A graph is essentially anything that can branch. Think of a cons as implementing branching --- nothing more, which means that it implments graphs, including trees. `(a . b)` is a pair -- two branches, if you like. Let either or both of `a` and `b` itself be a cons, and you can branch as far as you like. Either the `car` or the `cdr` of a cons (or both) can reference / *be* an ancestor (enclosing) cons = another way of saying that conses represent/implment / *are* graphs, not just trees.

Answer (score 2):

If you represent a (binary) tree with some form of nodes, we have several possible ways to represent them in Common Lisp.

We could define a node structure:

```
(defstruct node left right)
```

Then we have a function `MAKE-NODE`.

We could define a node class:

```
(defclass node ()
  (left right))
```

Nodes would be made with `(make-instance 'node)`.

We could make nodes with lists:

```
(defun make-node (left right)
  (list left right))
```

Above uses two cons cells.

We could make nodes for a binary tree a bit smaller with just one cons cell:

```
(defun make-node (left right)
  (cons left right))
```

We could make nodes as a vector:

```
(defun make-node (left right)
  (vector left right))
```

There are many possibilities. If the node should also have some other information, then the single cons cell approach is not enough. Something like a structure or class is fine, since the data item can have more information and the object knows its type: we can easily ask `(node-p something)` and get a useful answer.

The style rules for choosing the right data structure for any slightly more advanced software you want to write:

- by default use CLOS
- if CLOS is too slow (for example slot access is too slow), then try to optimize CLOS
- if CLOS is still too slow, then use structures. Slot access should be faster
- try to avoid representing data structures as untyped lists or cons trees

Comment: what does it mean, "try to optimize CLOS"? To optimize my CLOS-using user code, or to optimize how CLOS is implemented?

Comment: @Will Ness: some CLOS implementations have various ways to optimize slot access: primary classes, class sealing, circumventing slot-value-using-class, ... There are also other things which can be done to speed up CLOS-based code (like pre-fill caches for generic functions). For example I remember a talk by somebody whose company wrote a large CAD system using CLOS for the data structures. They needed some optimizations to CLOS - so that they did not have to use structures.

Comment: This is very good advice; I've fooled somewhat with Lisp data structure work, and CLOS never went wrong for me (albeit slightly slower). Using CAR/CDR was, as a rule, very fiddly and inflexible.

Answer (score 2):

He is just being cute when he asserts that the car is the right and the cdr is the left?

Recall that car/cdr arose originally on the IBM 704.  On that machine the car, i.e. the address part, of the words was the right side.   Figure 4 on page 8 of this [one of the 704 manuals](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Fortran/102653985.05.01.acc.pdf) illustrates that.  So I guess his presentation has some historical validity.

But I'd be curious if he actually has illustrations of lists like '(a b c d) drawn out using his left/right convention.

Comment: Good to know about the historical background...so far I haven't seen such illustrations from his book (but I am just starting as a novice)...I will report if I see such illustration one day... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is an error. The reason why it is an error is that conses correspond to a printed notation, and that printed notation goes left to right in a particular way.

Example:

```
(a b c d) <==> (a . (b . (c . (d . nil))))
```

This corresponds to the tree structure:

```
   .
  / \
 a   .
    / \
   b   .
      / \
     c   .
        / \
       d   nil
```

A tree is not a simple graph; the children are ordered.

If you say that `(a . b)` is a node with a left child `b` and right child `a`, it **goes against the convention of the notation you are using**, the meaning of left-and-right, and the direction of writing you're using.

If we are discussing Lisp, **the notation is given**: `car`-s are printed on the left, preceding the rest of the list. Mixing it up is not properly descriptive of the situation in Lisp, where we have to take into account everything, including the correspondence between symbolic expressions and internal structure.

If you're using Lisp conses to implement a binary data structure, and you do not care about any correspondence to Lisp's printed representation, you can assign left and right to `car` and `cdr` whichever way you like, of course, and the algorithm will work out. The convention in your code is not descriptive of the Lisp language, though.